# Discord - Webhook using JSON 400 bad request "embeds" "0"

Tags: json, discord, postman, embed

I've trying to learn JSON along with using web hooks.  I'm trying to use postman to test my code but I'm getting an error.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
POST /api/webhooks/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: discord.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: dbb93a2b-fced-8bd6-df89-XXXXXXXXXXX

{
"embeds": 
[{
"ticker": "{{ticker}}",
"exchange": "{{exchange}}",
"interval": "{{interval}}",
"date": "{{date}}",
"timenow": "{{timenow}}"
}]
}
```

error message

```
{
  "embeds": [
    "0"
  ]
}
```

Discord docs for JSON
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message

Comment: The rest of the request (excluding any authorization tokens) would be helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Error message
{
"embeds": [
"0"
]
}
means that you made a mistake in embed with 0 position.

In your case - fields 'ticker', 'exchange' and so on - don't exist in discord embeds format.